# Computing the limit of a sequence

Tags: calculus

I really need help with computing limit of sequences. I am actually really good in computing limits. But when it comes to this i get REALLY confused. i know i need to comput the limit as n approaches infinity but I really dont know how to do these questions.

1) Compute the limit of a sequence $$a_n = 3\ln(2n) - \ln(2n^3 + n^2)$$ if it converges.

2) Compute the limit of the sequence

$$a_n = \frac{e^n + 3^n + 2^n}{3^n}$$ if it converges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

for 1) $a_n = ln(2n)^3 - ln(2n^3+n^2) = ln(\frac{8n^3}{2n^3+n^2})$. Can you find the limit of the term inside the bracket?

for 2) $a_n = (\frac{e}{3})^n + 1 + (\frac{2}{3})^n$. Can you find the limit of all the terms as n goes to infinity?

Comment: so for a is the answer 2ln2?

Comment: yes, it's correct.

Answer (score 3):

**Hints:** For the first, recall that $k\ln x=\ln(x^k)$ and $\ln a-\ln b=\ln(a/b)$.  Then, if the answer is not clear, divide the top and bottom of the thing inside the $\ln$ by $n^3$.

For the second, divide top and bottom by $3^n$. In this case, it takes the simpler form: do  the division you are asked to do.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a start

$$ a_n = 3\ln(2n) - \ln(2n^3 + n^2)= \ln\left( \frac{(2n)^3}{2n^3+n^2} \right )=\dots. $$

Now, use the fact that the logarithm function is a continuous function to change the order of the limit as

$$ \lim \ln(a_n) = \ln(\lim a_n). $$

Comment: check your exponent